Lagging Video Feed Using VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest in macOS Camera Extension App
I'm developing a macOS application using Swift and a camera extension. I'm utilizing the Vision framework's VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest to apply a background blur effect. However, I'm experiencing significant lag in the video feed. I've tried optimizing the request, but the issue persists. Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to resolve this lagging issue?
class ViewController: NSViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    var frameCounter = 0
    let frameSkipRate = 2
    private let visionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.visionQueue")

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        frameCounter += 1
        if frameCounter % frameSkipRate != 0 {
            return
        }
        guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        performPersonSegmentation(on: ciImage) { [self] mask in
            guard let mask = mask else { return }
            let blurredBackground = self.applyBlur(to: ciImage)
            let resultImage = self.composeImage(with: blurredBackground, mask: mask, original: ciImage)
            let nsImage = ciImageToNSImage(ciImage: resultImage)
           
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                // Update your NSImageView or other UI elements with the composite image
                
                if needToStream {
                    if (enqueued == false || readyToEnqueue == true), let queue = self.sinkQueue {
                        enqueued = true
                        readyToEnqueue = false
                        if let _ = image, let cgImage = nsImage.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil) {
                            enqueue(queue, cgImage)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

 private func performPersonSegmentation(on image: CIImage, completion: @escaping (CIImage?) -> Void) {
        let request = VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest()
        request.qualityLevel = .fast // Adjust quality level as needed
        request.outputPixelFormat = kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image, options: [:])
        visionQueue.async {
            do {
                try handler.perform([request])
                guard let result = request.results?.first as? VNPixelBufferObservation else {
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }
                let maskPixelBuffer = result.pixelBuffer
                let maskImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: maskPixelBuffer)
                completion(maskImage)
            } catch {
                print("Error performing segmentation: \(error)")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
 private func composeImage(with blurredBackground: CIImage, mask: CIImage, original: CIImage) -> CIImage {
        // Invert the mask to blur the background
        let invertedMask = mask.applyingFilter("CIColorInvert")

        // Ensure mask is correctly resized to match original image
        let resizedMask = invertedMask.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: original.extent.width / invertedMask.extent.width, y: original.extent.height / invertedMask.extent.height))
        
        // Blend the images using the mask
        let blendFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithMask")!
        blendFilter.setValue(blurredBackground, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blendFilter.setValue(original, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
        blendFilter.setValue(resizedMask, forKey: kCIInputMaskImageKey)

        return blendFilter.outputImage ?? original
    }
  private func ciImageToNSImage(ciImage: CIImage) -> NSImage {
        let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)!
        return NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: ciImage.extent.size)
    }
 private func applyBlur(to image: CIImage) -> CIImage {
        let blurFilter = CIFilter.gaussianBlur()
        blurFilter.inputImage = image
        blurFilter.radius = 7.0 // Adjust the blur radius as needed
        return blurFilter.outputImage ?? image
    }
}


Are there any additional optimizations or configurations I can apply to reduce the lag?
Is there a more efficient way to handle real-time video processing using VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest?
Could there be an issue with the way I'm handling the video frames?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!`


Have you used Instruments to profile where exactly the time is spent? Maybe you could try to render your output directly to a layer, instead of converting to an NSImage? I believe that would be faster, as no additional object would need to be created.

@fabianm thanks for this i have already use time instrument when we remove VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest fremowrk code it is working fine  only below calculation code take time  let request = VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest()
request.qualityLevel = .fast // Adjust quality level as needed
request.outputPixelFormat = kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image, options: [:])
